# Scanning folder to find all files with minimum matching words (UNIX)

Tags: regex, unix, match

Having some trouble figuring out the command line to the following issue and hoping u guys can help!

Basically, I have a folder which contains a ~1000 PDF's. I need to search through every pdf and return the file names of PDF's that match certain words X amount of times.

For example, I have 10 PDF's which all contain the word "Fragile". I would like to return a list of all files that contain "Fragile" a minimum of 3 times throughout the PDF.

I am currently using pdfgrep and giving it a regex to look for, but it will return all the files that match at least once. I have seen a few recommendations out there piping the command with "awk", but i'm not sure what this really does...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about pdfgrep, but if the output is like on https://pdfgrep.org/ it should be fairly easy to get the number of the lines in the output, doing something like:

```
for f in *.pdf; do if [ $(pdfgrep -nHm 10 "Fragile" "$f" | wc -l) -gt 2 ]; then echo $f; fi; done
```